# Capturing beautifulsoup HTMLParseError exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am getting the exception from Beutifulsoup `HTMLParseError: expected name token at u'<![0Y', at line 1371, column 24` - arising because the html I am reading in is malformed.

How do I capture this error - I have tried

```
 try: 
     ... 
 except HTMLParseError:
     pass
```

but that results in the error `NameError: global name 'HTMLParseError' is not defined`

I have also tried `except BeautifulSoup.HTMLParseError:` but that then gives the error `AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'`

More broadly, when i get an custom error from a package i am using, how is it possible to "work out" what the exception needs to be to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is raising HTMLParseError from the HTMLParser library. Try importing the error from that library before using it in your try/except:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParseError

try:
    # error happens
except HTMLParseError:
    pass
```

More info on the HTMLParse library is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

See where error is raised in BeautifulSoup source code  [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py).

Answer (score -3):

have you tried catch NameError exception?

if you can't catch it try this:

```
try:
    # error happens
except Exception as e:
    # log the exception here
    print(e)
```

Comment: I think the `NameError` exception is only arising because `except HTMLParseError` is not valid, so checking for that is not really a solution. I'd also prefer to avoid the 'catch-all' solution.